# draw bitmap between 2 points android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, rect

I want to draw a bitmap between 2 points android but not able to do it.i am trying to draw a rect and then draw bitmap within it.But thats also not working.

```
  RectF rect = new RectF(challengePoint.x, challengePoint.y,userChallenge.getChallenge().getCityPinDest().getPosition().x, userChallenge.getChallenge().getCityPinDest().getPosition().y);
            Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapMainView.getResources(), R.drawable.path1);


            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, null, rect , null);
```

Kindly help me to draw  a custom path between two points.i don't want to draw a simple line instead i have a path.png which i want to place between 2 points in canvas